# Access Point Analysis

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

How is it possible for an AP (Access Point) to show 2 separate channels i.e. 6 and 4, when a survey is conducted.  The SSID and BSSID are the same but the channels are different.

Channel 4 appeared during a Gmon survey and 6 appeared on the network analysis card.

On dual band routers is the 5GHz band switchable so if you wanted, you could knock it back to 2.4GHz?

The BSSID identifies the AP as a TP Link product. The research is part of a Network analysis course and I'm not very clued up on this area of analysis.

Answer (score 0):

In 2.4GHz, the channels overlap to a great degree. When the signal is strong enough, it's possible to see packets from up to 4 channels away. It may be that your network is actually on 6, but one of your scanning tools happened to see a beacon from it when the tool happened to be tuned to channel 4 at the time.